# How can I display a string that contains HTML with quotes in twig template?

Tags: html, symfony, twig

How can I display a string (variable `imgStr`) that contains HTML with quotes in twig template?

String is :

```
 <img src="{{ asset( 'bundles/meeting/images/uploads/c986889a9912f69f6324d5c79c2d072119411384.png') }}" height="500" />
```

1) If i use raw filer  `<br> {{ imgStr|raw }} <br>` i am getting empty square instead of image. I believe the reason is ''/"" quotes inside the string.

2) How to use function `template_from_string`? According official documentation, i must add the `Twig_Extension_StringLoader` extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment. But i do not understand how to make this in Symfony2. I also did not find this function in `Vendor/twig/extensions` .

Comment: Does your string really contain HTML and Twig code?

Comment: Yes it contains html and symfony2 twig extension "asset". I achieved my aim - images display, using only ~img.filename~ instead of whole string. But it is still interesting if it is possible to add raw string with quotes ( ' and " ) as html in twig.

Comment: Can you try `{{ "#{imgStr}" }}` with may eval twig function `asset` in your variable with "string interpolation" see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation

Answer (score 2):

You can try loading the template_from_string extension declaring it as a service. Here you have it in yml format:

```
myproject.load_template_from_string:
  class: Twig_Extension_StringLoader
  tags:
    - { name: twig.extension }
```

This way the extension is loaded on the compiler pass and then you can use it like this:

```
{% set router = "<script src=\"{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}\"></script>" %}
{{ include(template_from_string(router))}}
```

Note: I had to escape the variable because it's declared inline on the same template, but it should work without a hitch with variables passed to the template.